# Why $match doesn't work when not using dot notation

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to match a nested field after a lookup but it doesn't work.

```
   {
     "$match": {
       "test2": {
         "test": true
       }
     }
   }
```

If I try to match with dot notation it works.

```
   {
     "$match": {
       "test2.test": true
     }
   }
```

**Why doesn't it work when I'm using an object ?**

*This is the Aggregation pipeline that I used for testing matching.*

```
var pipeline = [
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "test2",
                "localField": "test2",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "test2"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$unwind": {
                "path": "$test2"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "$match": {
                "test2": {
                    "test": true
                }
            }
        }
    ];
```

Comment: It won't because, nested element will match through dot notation or [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html)

Comment: But as I mentioned it works on embedded documents. After using unwind on the field that i looked up , it shouldn't behave like a embedded document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to `$match:{ test2: { test: true } }`

But

```
{ test2: { test: true } } != { test2: { test: true, _id:<num> } }
```

dot notation will match both.

Comment: @GeorgeSofianos you're welcome, mongoDB is very nice but sometimes it gets confusing. I feel it everyday.